# Makefile - compiles all files everytime

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

Here is my makefile that i am using to build a library. It works well. But it always recompiles all the files. I have declared .PHONY. Still the problem is there.

```
PROGRAM=mylib


[...]
OBJS= dir/file1.o \
          dir/file2.o

SRC= $(addprefix dir/,$(OBJS))

.PHONY: all clean install
all: ${SRC}
    ${CC} --shared -o lib${PROGRAM}.so ${OBJS}

%.o: %.c
    ${CC} -c ${MY_CFLAGS} $*.c ${INCLUDES}
```

Also if there are any major concerns with my Makefile please comment.

File tree is as follows :

```
my_lib
├── include
│   ├── file1.h
└── src
    ├── file1.c
    ├── file2.c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SRC_FILES` contains `src/file1.o` and `src/file2.o` and so on. This is most likely not what you want. By doing this and the `$*.c` in the generic .c to .o rule you're breaking `make's` file-rule-dependency automatism.

I'd rewrite your Makefile like this:

```
[..]

all: lib${PROGRAM}.so     # create dependency from all to your .so

lib${PROGRAM}.so: ${OBJECT_FILES}     # create a dep for your .so to all object files
     ${CC} ${SHARED_FLAGS} -o lib${PROGRAM}.so ${OBJECT_FILES}

%.o: %.c  # generic rule to build .o from .c
     $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(MY_CFLAGS)
```

${OBJECT_FILES} has to contain src/file1.o if file1.c is located in src/

The generic rule needs the .o in the same directory as the .c-file.

Comment: Hi Patrick. I updated my post with tree structure of files. I have named badly SRC_FILES, But i meant OBJ_FILES itself. For my tree structure compilation with your changes is failing "make: *** No rule to make target `file1.c', needed by `libmylib.so'.  Stop." I am still looking if my changes are bad. Thank you

Comment: ${OBJECT_FILES} has to contain src/file1.o is file1.c is located in src/

Comment: Is it not possible to create object files in a different directory and tell the Makefile to check from there?

Comment: Have you considered using a Makefile-generator like for example `cmake`. Not only it will take away from you the dependency problem, but it will give you the out-of-source-build-possibility. Which is .o-file are generated outside the source tree. This implicitly solves your path-problem.

Comment: I din't know about cmake. I will try it now.! Thank you.!